# setAdapter() returning null within ListFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

So I'm trying to make a basic foreground for another app I'm making.
I'm just trying to get a listView to populate on screen within my fragment. (To create swipe-able tab views)

I keep getting a nullPointerException on this line here:

```
List.setAdapter(Adapter);
```

Here's my entire class:

```
public class List_View extends ListFragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listviewtest, container, false);
    ListView List = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listView1); 

    List<HashMap<String, String>> Data = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    {
        HashMap<String, String> temp1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
        temp1.put("Item", "Item 1");
        Data.add(temp1);
        HashMap<String, String> temp2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
        temp2.put("Item", "Item 2");
        Data.add(temp2);
        HashMap<String, String> temp3 = new HashMap<String, String>();
        temp3.put("Item", "Item 3");
        Data.add(temp3);
    }

    SimpleAdapter Adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this.getActivity(),
            Data, R.layout.custom_row_view, new String[] {
                    "Item" }, new int[] { R.id.text1});

    List.setAdapter(Adapter);

    List.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            switch (position) {

            case 1:
                AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        getActivity());
                dlgAlert.setMessage("Set Message Text");
                dlgAlert.setTitle("Set Message Title");
                dlgAlert.setNeutralButton("View info",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {

                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });

                dlgAlert.setCancelable(false);
                dlgAlert.create().show();

                break;
            }
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}
}
```

So far as I can tell this shouldn't be returning null..

Comment: Try `ListView List = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView1);`

Answer (score 2):

I'm thinking your inflate operation is returning null. Check this line

```
ListView List = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listView1);
```

You should be inflating your ListView from your parent view of your fragment, not from the parent activity.

Should be something like this instead

```
ListView List = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView1);  and make sure that
```